# How to convert geometry of shapefile to decimals

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, pyqgis

I try to create a line with two points. These points are obtained in a shapefile layer.

How can I convert that points to decimals?

Comment: Could you clarify what you are looking for? After all, converting a (geometric) point into a "decimal" makes no sense on the face of it. Are you asking, perhaps, for a base-ten decimal representation of point *coordinates* to be output?  (If so, what does that have to do with creating a line [segment] from two points?)

Comment: I take two points from shapefine and I want to create a line with QgsVectorLayer. I need points in decimals to the function QgsGeometry.fromPolyline

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is covered in "Points2One" and "Points to Paths" plugins. You can take code from there.